# Github actions posts comments on my fork but not on the original repo. Why?

Tags: github, token, benchmarking, github-actions

There is a githubs actions which compares the difference between benchmark performance on every PR. The gh actions repo link - https://github.com/smrpn/criterion-compare-action/tree/move_to_actions

This is the code reponsible for posting comments -

```js
const resultsAsMarkdown = convertToMarkdown(myOutput);

  // An authenticated instance of `@octokit/rest`
  const octokit = github.getOctokit(myToken);

  const contextObj = { ...context.issue };

  try {
    await octokit.issues.createComment({
      owner: contextObj.owner,
      repo: contextObj.repo,
      issue_number: contextObj.number,
      body: resultsAsMarkdown,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // If we can't post to the comment, display results here.
    // forkedRepos only have READ ONLY access on GITHUB_TOKEN
    // https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/quot-Resource-not-accessible-by-integration-quot-for-adding-a/td-p/33925
    const resultsAsObject = convertToTableObject(myOutput);
    console.table(resultsAsObject);
    console.log("Failed to comment", e);
    core.debug(e);
    core.debug("Failed to comment");
  }
```

This posts the result as a comment on my fork of the repo -
[comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svlZ9.png)

But not on the original repo -
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdBHV.png)

This is my .yml file -

```yaml
on: [pull_request]
name: Benchmarks
jobs:
  runBenchmark:
    name: run benchmark
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: stable
          override: true
          profile: minimal
      - name: Cache cargo
        uses: actions/cache@v2.1.4
        with:
          path: |
            target
            ~/.cargo/git
            ~/.cargo/registry
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}
      - uses: smrpn/criterion-compare-action@move_to_actions 
        with:
          cwd: benches
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I want this PR to post comments on the original repo. What is the error here? What is the fix?

Comment: Did you read the comment in it that says why, or follow the link for more details?

Comment: on `pull_request_target` I guess it should work, it does run the action in the original repo, not on the forked one. But as mentioned in the answer by Stephen Cleary, it can be risky and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post that goes into detail about security when running actions for PRs from forked repo's: https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/

The blog post includes an example for how this kind of operation should be handled. Building and benchmarking performance on a PR is potentially dangerous, so it has to be done with the `pull_request` trigger; for security reasons, `pull_request` does not have permissions to add a comment. Instead, the `pull_request` trigger workflow should do the build and performance benchmark and then upload the results as artifacts.

Then a different workflow will trigger on `workflow_run`. This workflow has higher permissions (specifically, it can add a comment). It should download the artifacts that were uploaded from the `pull_request` workflow and post them as a comment to the PR.